# returning a new row for each record

Tags: mysql, sql

in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360072/left-outer-join-question) I asked how to return id's  from 3 different tables if the user_id was matched to a record in each of these tables. the sql-

```
select
    (select id from bla_facebook_accts where user_id = user.user_id) as facebook,
    (select id from bla_linked_in_accts where user_id = user.user_id) as linkedin,
    (select id from bla_twitter_accts where user_id = user.user_id) as twitter
from
    (select 12 user_id) user
```

Works great, but I would like each the select statements that return a whether or not each of the tables has a record to return a new row, and return multiple rows if a table has more than one record for each .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. This will also return the source table of the information.

```
SELECT'facebook' source, id FROM bla_facebook_accts WHERE (user_id = 12)
UNION
SELECT 'linkedin' source, id FROM bla_linked_in_accts WHERE (user_id = 12)
UNION
SELECT'twitter' source, id FROM bla_twitter_accts WHERE (user_id = 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use a `UNION` construct:

```
select id from bla_facebook_accts where user_id = 12
UNION 
select id from bla_linked_in_accts where user_id = 12
UNION 
select id from bla_twitter_accts where user_id = 12
```

Comment: i still would like to have the OUTER kind of query which returns an empty field for the other two tables